# Unix command to remove a file that can't be retrieved at any cost

Tags: unix

rm command removes only the reference and not the actual data from the disk, so that can be retrieved later, is there any command that delete the reference and the data at the same time.

Comment: Just guessing: you can get the address of the file and write something there

Comment: Yes that would be helpful, can we write at a specific location though ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you need.

If need to reclaim the storage space without waiting for all the processes that hold the file open to close it or die, invoke `truncate -s 0 FILENAME` to free the data, and then remove the file with a regular `rm FILENAME`. The two operations will not be atomic, though, and the programs that have already opened the file can fail in various ways (including a segmentation fault, if they have mapped some portions of the file into memory). However, given that you intend to delete both the file and its contents, there is no general way to prevent the programs that depend on the contents from failing.

If your goal is for the data to not be retrievable with forensic analysis after removal, use a command such as [`shred`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_(Unix)), which is specifically designed to overwrite the data before removing the file. And - pay close attention to the limitations of such tools before trusting them to reliably destroy sensitive data.

Comment: in AIX version it is not woking, can you tell in which version shred works ?

Comment: @VivekKeshri `shred` is not a standard Unix command, so you might need to install it first. If the command is present, but malfunctioning, you will need to report a bug, or debug it yourself. Unfortunately, in-depth help with these issues is well outside the scope of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If, as your comment suggests, you are on OSX, you can use `srm` to do "*secure removals*".

```
SRM(1)                                                                  SRM(1)

NAME
       srm - securely remove files or directories

SYNOPSIS
       srm [OPTION]... FILE...

DESCRIPTION
       srm  removes each specified file by overwriting, renaming, and truncat-
       ing it before unlinking. This prevents other people from undeleting  or
       recovering any information about the file from the command line.
```

Online manpage is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/srm.1.html).

Alternatively, `shred` is available within the *GNU coreutils*, which you can easily install on OS X using `homebrew`, with the command

```
brew install coreutils
```